# How to construct a column based on other columns using dataframe in Spark Java?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to make a column based on other columns. I have this dataframe DF1:

```
---------------------
  a   | b    | c    |
------|------|------|
value1|value2|value3|
------|------|------|
```

The expected result is that I add a column d with the values of the columns a, b and c separated with "|":

```
------------------------------------------
  a   | b    | c    | d
------|------|------|---------------------
value1|value2|value3|value1|value2|value3
------|------|------|---------------------
```

How can I do this in Spark Java using dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expr("concat('|',*)")`, Check below code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df.withColumn("d",expr("concat_ws('|',*)")).show(false)
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|a     |b     |c     |d                   |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|value1|value2|value3|value1|value2|value3|
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: ```expr``` is available in org.apache.spark.sql.functions package, try to import into your code.